# Empty vector toolbar in QGIS

Tags: qgis, toolbar

I've just installed QGIS 3.34 on Windows 10. The vector toolbar is empty. I've tried to de/reactivate it but it remains empty, as well as many other suggestions in forums, but it does not improve.

Any idea how I can solve it?

Comment: It would be good to briefly summarise what you have tried, otherwise you will likely get the same suggestions.

Comment: That is normal. The default QGIS installation has nothing to place into the Vector toolbar. The toolbar is used by some vector plug-ins. See gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183454/…. I tested that activating for example the topology checker plug-in adds an icon to the vector toolbar with QGIS 3.37.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the empty space somewhere near the top:

[image]

That gives you this selection panel:

[image]

Select what you want to see.

Comment: Thanks! I think I was actually looking for the Digitinzing toolbar... thanks for the support.

Comment: Welcome. Accepting the answer if it has solved your problem is good practice in general :)